# CSS Print - Strange artifacts only appear in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am currently developing a JS/HTML application and there is a HTML page that I require to print. The layout of the page looks like

```
    <div class="customerOffer">
        <div class="buttonHeader"><span class="backButton">Back</span><span class="printButton">Print</span></div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panelTitle"><span class="text">Title</span></div>
            <div class="panelBox">
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="row"><span class="label b">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                    <div class="row"><span class="label b">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                    <div class="row"><span class="label b">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                    <div class="row"><span class="label b">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                    <div class="row"><span class="label b">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                    <div class="row"><span class="label b">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="column right">
                    <div class="row"><span class="label b">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                    <div class="row"><span class="label b">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                    <div class="row"><span class="label b">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panelTitle"><span class="text">Title</span></div>
            <div class="panelBox">
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="separator"></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row important"><span class="label b">Text</span><span class="inputValueF b">£0.00</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panelTitle"><span class="text">Title</span></div>
            <div class="panelBox">
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="separator"></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row coloured"><span class="label">Text</span><span class="inputValueF">£0.00</span></div>
                <div class="row important"><span class="label b">Text</span><span class="inputValueF b">£0.00</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see the page is made up of a number of "Panels" which have a title bar and some information inside of them. To keep the page from 'breaking' inside one of these panels when printing I added `page-break-inside: avoid;` to these panels in the `@media print` tag for this page. Here is the LESS for this HTML page

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);

@accent: #5280B8;
@secondary: #1e518d;
@background-blue: #4e96e7;
@panel: #FFFFFF;
//@rowOdd: #EFF2F6;
@rowOdd: lighten(@accent, 38%);
@rowEven: #FFFFFF;
@input-background: #e4e4e4;
@button-grey: #c6c7c8;

.button-template{
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    padding: 1px 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: @accent;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 25px;

    &:hover{
        background-color: darken(@accent, 10%);
    }
    &:active{
        background-color: darken(@accent, 20%);
    }
    &:focus{
        outline: none;
    }
}

* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(http://media.ca-a.com/MEDIA/OEM/NISSAN/GB/BG/NissanBG.png);

    &:before{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        content: ' ';
        position: absolute;
        background-color: @background-blue;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        opacity: 0.66;
    }

    .customerOffer{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: gray;
        position: absolute;
        left: 200%;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 1;

        &:before{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            content: ' ';
            position: absolute;
            background-color: @background-blue;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            opacity: 0.66;
        }

        .buttonHeader{
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            position: relative;

            .backButton{
                .button-template;
                left: 20px;
                position: relative;
            }
            .printButton{
                .button-template;
                margin-right: 10px;
                left: calc(~"89% - 20px");
                position: relative;
            }
        }

        .panel{
            width: calc(~"100% - 40px");
            overflow: hidden;
            border-radius: 10px;
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;

            .panelTitle{
                width: 100%;
                height: 38px;
                background-color: @accent;

                .text{
                    line-height: 38px;
                    font-size: 18px;
                    font-weight: 500;
                    color: #fff;
                    position: relative;
                    left: 30px;
                }
            }

            .panelBox{
                height: auto;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: justify;
                background-color: @panel;
                border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;

                .column{
                    padding-right: 0px;
                    height: 100%;
                    padding-left: 0px;
                    width: 50%;
                    vertical-align: top;
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin-top: 5px;

                    &.right{
                        float: right;
                    }                  
                }

                .row{
                    margin-bottom: 8px;

                    &:last-child{
                        border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
                    }

                    &.coloured{
                        margin-bottom: 0px;
                        padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px;

                        &:nth-child(odd){
                            background-color: @rowOdd;
                        }
                        &:nth-child(even){
                            background-color: @rowEven;
                        }

                        .label{
                            width: auto;
                        }

                        .inputValueF{
                            float: right;
                            margin-right: 10px;

                            &.b{
                                font-weight: bold;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    &.important{
                        margin-bottom: 0px;
                        padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
                        background-color: @secondary;

                        .label{
                            color: @panel;
                            width: auto;
                        }

                        .inputValueF{
                            color: @panel;
                            float: right;
                            margin-right: 10px;

                            &.b{
                                font-weight: bold;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    .label{
                        vertical-align: top;
                        display: inline-block;
                        width: 100px;
                        margin-left: 20px;

                        &.b{
                            font-weight: bold;
                        }
                    }

                    .inputValueF{
                        display: inline-block;
                    }
                }

                .separator{
                    height: 2px;
                    background-color: #212121;
                    width: 98%;
                    margin-left: 1%;
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}

@media print{

    div{
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    .wrapper{
        overflow: visible;
        width: 210mm;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-image: none;
        //-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;

        &:before{
            display: none;
        }

        .customerOffer{
            background-color: transparent;
            background-image: none;
            position: initial;
            overflow: visible;

            &:before{
                display: none;
            }

            .buttonHeader{
                display: none;
            }

            .panelTitle{
                //box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px @accent;
                border: 2px solid @accent
            }

            .panelBox{
                border: 2px solid @accent;

                .row{
                    &.coloured{

                        &:nth-child(odd){
                            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px @rowOdd;
                        }
                        &:nth-child(even){
                            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px @rowEven;
                        }
                    }

                    &.important{
                        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px @secondary;

                        .label{
                            color: @panel;
                        }

                        .inputValueF{
                            color: @panel;
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I print this page in Firefox I get the output I expected.
[image]

But when I print it in Chrome, you can see a phantom panelTitle element at the very bottom of the first page. I can only reproduce this with the `page-break-inside: avoid;` CSS, as otherwise the print will break inside one of the Panels.
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas how to remove this phantom element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the issue appears when using the `margin` property with an `@page` directive.

At the bottom of my CSS I had

```
@page{
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */ 

    /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */ 
    margin: 5mm 0mm 5mm 0mm;  
}
```

If I reduced the margin to `5mm 0mm 0mm 0mm` then the issue will disappear but this obviously produces other issues. Luckily it seems that the printers I have tested this with will not print (by default atleast) 5mm from the edge of the page so it does not appear when physically printing the document.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the default page margins are different as well as the spacing between elements are also inconsistent between the firefox and chrome print.

Perhaps using [page-break](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/) to ensure that new table starts on a new page and is not split between two pages.

Comment: I am already using `page-break-inside: avoid;` to place the 3rd Panel on a new page.